# Есть две dll библиотеки с одинаковыми названиями и namespace нужно сохранить оба

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exchange

У меня в моем приложении есть изначально библиотека Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices
которую нельзя трогать.(так как это коробочное лицензионное решение на который распространяется техническая поддержка вендора)
Сейчас я хочу добавить dll из https://github.com/sherlock1982/ews-managed-api/ но при добавлении, из за того что эта dll имеет то же название и те же namespace и методы, функционал коробки конфликтует.
Поэтому нужна помощь в сборке dll из этой  github.com/sherlock1982/ews-managed-api ветки с более уникальными именем и названием пространства имен.

P.S. Сам я никогда не создавал свои собственные dll

Comment: @aepot Отредактировал полностью вопрос.

Comment: Пробовал через notepad поменять все using и namespace функционал не конфликтует и не работает.

Comment: [extern alias](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias)

Comment: @aepot Уже натыкался. Но я не могу редактировать коробочное решение чтобы прописать extern alias

Comment: Поэтому только способ с библиотекой расматриваю.

Comment: git clone себе библиотеку, открыть sln файл в Visual Studio, поменять namespace, собрать.

Comment: Во-первых, менять полностью суть вопроса - плохо. Во-вторых, в чем сейчас ваш вопрос состоит? В том, чтоб за вас отредактировали и собрали библиотеку и скинули вам или что? Если да, то я голосую за закрытие, ибо такому не место на SO, а если нет, то конкретизируйте, поставьте более точный вопрос, на который можно было бы найти одно, конкретное решение.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Просто подсказать как быстрее всего это сделать. Собирать её кому то не нужно, просто я не знаю всех нюансов. Вдруг если поменяю все namespace придётся еще что то менять чтобы VS адекватно собрало это. Так как сделав это через notepad заменой текста у меня обе библиотеки перестали хоть как то работать.

Comment: Студия сама вам поменяет тексты везде где надо. Не надо мудрить ничего с блокнотом. Переименовываете, студия обводит вам слово пунктиром, жмете `Ctrl+.`, и выбираете переименовать.

Comment: @aepot можно считать ответом.

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, как и что у вас может конфликтовать. Оттого, что библиотека использует ту же dll, которую хотите использовать вы, никаких проблем быть не должно. Опишите подробней.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю, то трудность возникает в конфликте имен, причем не только самих классов, а так же using, который подключается. Для таких случаев Microsoft позаботился о создании псевдонимов для Dll, их название уже не может повторяться в одном каталоге. Используются они довольно просто и дабы не повторять статью, даю ссылку на нее: [Псевдоним extern](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias)